# Parse variables from JSON, then loop through on several url with variables with curl

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am new to jq. My business problem is the following: I have several GPS location address stored in several JSON.
JSON format is like:

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "Date": "2018-06-19T06:02:12+02:00",
        "Latitude": 46.54225,
        "Longitude": 17.13874,
        "Type": "GPS",
        "Speed(mph)": 0,
        "Speed(km/h)": 0,
        "Direction": null,
        "Altitude(ft)": 406,
        "Altitude(m)": 124,
        "Accuracy": 50
    },
    {
        "Date": "2018-06-19T06:59:49+02:00",
        "Latitude": 46.53973,
        "Longitude": 17.06964,
        "Type": "GPS",
        "Speed(mph)": 1,
        "Speed(km/h)": 2,
        "Direction": 208,
        "Altitude(ft)": 377,
        "Altitude(m)": 115,
        "Accuracy": 10
    }]
}
```

I want to loop trough on the Latitude and Longitude values, store them in two variables one-by-one, and with these variables I want to call the Google's reverse geocoding rest API with shell script with every long-lat pair:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=[VARIABLE1],[VARIABLE2]&key=APIKEYHERE

In an other Stackoverflow question, there was a similar question. Thanks to that question, I tried something like this, but obviously the variables are not working properly:

```
"error_message" : "Invalid request. Invalid 'latlng' parameter.",
"results" : [],
"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
```

Code:

```
jq -rc '.Latitude + " " +.Longitude' /usr/location/archive/location_1806181400.json |
while read -r Latitude Longitude; do
    curl https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$Latitude,$Longitude&key=APIKEYHERE
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `jq` filter, you need to do an interpolation logic as below to put the values out in a CSV format, which you can parse out using a shell loop.

```
jq -r '(.Data[] | "\(.Latitude),\(.Longitude)")'
```

Now putting this in a loop

```
jq -r '(.Data[] | "\(.Latitude),\(.Longitude)")' /usr/location/archive/location_1806181400.json |
   while IFS=, read -r lat long; do
       curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${long}&key=APIKEYHERE"
   done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
jq -r '.Data[] | "\(.Latitude) \(.Longitude)"' /usr/location/archive/location_1806181400.json | while read l g; do 
  curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${l},${g}&key=APIKEYHERE"; 
done
```

which is almost the same as yours, except for the `jq` script and the quoting for the `curl` command.